# Need help properly saving copied range from excel file into separate files based on range in VBS

Tags: excel, vbscript

I'm working on a VB Script that will take an Excel spreadsheet and split it up into four separate files based on a range I specify.

I have it working, but I'm having difficulty only saving the copied cells...I'm getting the copied cells AND the entire population.

```
Set oExcelWorkbook = oExcelObject.Workbooks.Open("C:\TEST\sample.xlsx")

oExcelWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(sRange1).Copy
oExcelWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
oExcelWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").SaveAs "C:\TEST\file1.xlsx", 51

oExcelWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(sRange2).Copy
oExcelWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").PasteSpecial
oExcelWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").SaveAs "C:\TEST\file2.xlsx", 51

oExcelWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(sRange3).Copy
oExcelWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").PasteSpecial
oExcelWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").SaveAs "C:\TEST\file3.xlsx", 51

oExcelWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(sRange4).Copy
oExcelWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").PasteSpecial
oExcelWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").SaveAs "C:\TEST\file4.xlsx", 51
```

Each file has the entire population in SHEET1 and the requested range population in SHEET2.

I only want the four files to contain the results copied to SHEET2

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: One way would be to re-open the saved files and delete "Sheet1" from them. Another would be to create a new workbook before pasting, saving and closing it.

Comment: What is the range value of your ranges? (i.e. **sRange1, sRange2, sRange3, sRange4**)

Comment: You need to Copy Sheet2 to create a new workbook, then save and close that new workbook.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks....that method worked perfectly!